# Re-committing a commit that was reverted in git

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-revert

Having a few issues committing my code changes from my working branch back into a branch it was revert out of. My code was put into the release branch early and had to be reverted for another release, how do I then merge these changes back into the release branch as git says there are no changes being made when I merge.

I am unable to revert the revert commit or cherry pick my commits from the release branch as Gitlab doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: Probably you can stash your version, cherrypick and stash+pop to realign your local version. finally commit + push

Comment: @Glauco When you mean stash my version do you mean stash my commits? I thought you can only stash commits that have not already been pushed to my repository?

Comment: Yes, stash works only on local changes, not yet committed.

Comment: @Glauco Sadly the changes are already committed but I have figured out a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this,

I had to create a branch from a tag that was before the revert and the commits and cherry pick from my working branch into this branch to put it ahead of the revert commits. This allowed me to push this branch back into my Dev branch to reapply my changes.

Comment: If you want to keep the latest updates in main branch where you did a revert, create another branch from it so that the new branch has all the updates and then cherry pick your changes from your working branch to the new branch. As cherry pick creates new commits, your changes will now show up in the main branch. As long as the same commit hash is present in both the main branch and the working branch, no changes would be shown.